# Haskell Higher Order Functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, recursion-schemes

I have a homework on higher order functions in Haskell and I'm having a little trouble getting started.

If I could get some help and explanation on the first question, I'm confident I can finish the rest.

> Using higher order functions (`map`, `fold`, or `filter`), and if necessary
>   lambda expressions, write functions `f1` and `f2` such that `f1 (f2 (*) [1,2,3,4]) 5 ~> [5,10,15,20]`

```
f1 = 
f2 =
```

I'm thinking I have to use a partially applied `map` so that `[1,2,3,4]` becomes `[(*1),(*2),(*3),(*4)]` ?

Comment: I'd say you should start with `f1 g n = g n` and then write f2 such that `f2 (+) [1..4] 5 == [5,10,15,20]`

Comment: Yes, `f2 = map` sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm thinking I have to use a partially evaluated map so that [1,2,3,4] becomes [*1,*2,*3,*4] ??

Your intuition brings you closer to the answer, so that's a good sign

That said, the expression you're given to work with is really weird

```
f1 (f2 (*) [1,2,3,4]) 5
```

I would write `f1` and `f2` as follows

```
let f1 = \xs n -> map (\f -> f n) xs
    f2 = map
in f1 (f2 (*) [1,2,3,4]) 5
-- [5,10,15,20]
```

Comment: Of if you want to get fancy, `f1 = flip (map . flip ($))` :-D

Comment: Your answer explains nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you take `f2 = map`, you immediately get to the first step that you've come up with:

```
f2 (*) [1, 2, 3, 4] =
map (*) [1, 2, 3, 4] =
[(1 *), (2 *), (3 *), (4 *)]
```

Now given this list of multiplier functions, we need

```
f1 [g1, g2, ..., gn] x =
[g1 x, g2 x, ..., gn x]
```

since then we can apply it on `f2 (*) [1..4]` to get

```
f1 [(1 *), (2 *), (3 *), (4 *)] 5 =
[1 * 5, 2 * 5, 3 * 5, 4 * 5] =
[5, 10, 15, 20]
```

which is what you're after.

If you look at `f1`, it looks almost like a `map`, except the arguments are `flip`ped:

```
f1 = \gs x -> map h gs
```

Now we just need to figure out what `h` is. `h` needs to be something that takes a function like `(2 *)` and gives you the result of applying that function to `5`; i.e. `h = \g -> g 5`.

Putting it all together, we get

```
let f2 = map
    f1 = \gs x -> map (\g -> g x) gs
in f1 (f2 (*) [1, 2, 3, 4]) 5
```